# PHP Unique Hit Counter Does Not Work

Tags: php, file, count, ip, fwrite

I'm trying to make a unique hit counter with PHP based on the IP address of the user.

This is my attempt:

```
$ip_address = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];

function hit_count(){
    $ip_file = file('ip.txt');
    foreach($ip_file as $ip){
        $ip_single = trim($ip);
        if($ip_address == $ip_single){
            $found = true;
            break;
        }else{
            $found = false;
        }
    }
    if($found == false){
        $filename = "count.txt";
        $handle = fopen($filename,"r");
        $current = fread($handle,filesize($filename));
        fclose($handle);
        $current_inc = $current + 1;
        $handle = fopen($filename,"w");
        fwrite($handle,$current_inc);
        fclose($handle);
        $handle = fopen("ip.txt","a");
        fwrite($handle,$ip_address."\n");
        fclose($handle);
    }
}
```

As you can see it pretty much takes the IP address of the user and then calls the text document `ip.txt`. So if the comparison of user's IP address was not matched with the IP address that is stored in that text document, it will return *false*.

And after that, it opens up `count.txt` in order to count the hits. In the end, it will add the IP address to `ip.txt` as well.

But now the problem with this code is that it does not do what it must do. I mean both text files are empty even after the execution.

And no errors also appear because the codes are written correctly.

So my question is, what is wrong with this code, and how can I fix that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: using an ip address for this purpose would not be fully reliable - several users can share a public ip address ( corporate network for example ) ~ you might be better using `fingerprinting`  -  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_fingerprint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had created a similar functionality a few days back. here is my code do try it out.

```
<?php
$filename = 'count.txt';
$ip_filename = 'ip.txt';
function hit_count(){
    $ip = get_ip();
    global $filename, $ip_filename;

    if(!in_array($ip, file($ip_filename, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES))){
        $current_value = (file_exists($filename)) ? file_get_contents($filename) : 0;
        file_put_contents($ip_filename, $ip."\n", FILE_APPEND);
        file_put_contents($filename, ++$current_value);
    }
}
function get_ip(){
if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])){
    $ip_address = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
}else if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])){
    $ip_address = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
}else{
    $ip_address = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}
return $ip_address;
}
hit_count();
?>
```

Comment: should that be a call to `hit_count();` at the bottom rather than `inc_count();`?